# Keeping files in one server and media files in another server

Tags: database, importexport, server

we have a magento site with thousands of products. it will grow for millions 
so we are worrying about performance of the server.

we are planning to put media folder [ images ] in one server and files in another server.
we bought a magento extension to upload products through excel sheet . but when we are uploading excel sheet, site will load very slowly and backend will not open.
is there any way we can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your shop loads very slow during import, then it's not the media folder you need to move to another server, you must move your database. also it all depends on your server specs. if your server is small and have not much CPU and RAM then it will be slow.

but if you still need to move media, then you must have LAN connection between servers, and you need to mount media folder from another server into local server.

sometimes it's even easier to mount/insert another separate drive. or even use SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Create a Sub-domain named "media.mytestsite.com".
2. Copy the media folder to your sub-domain's root folder.
3. Give the permission 777 to media folder. (Full permission).
4. Go to you magento admin.
   Go to `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Unsecure -> Base Media URL and put "http://media.mytestsite.com/media/"`.

5.Go to `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Secure -> Base Media URL and put "https://media.mytestsite.com/media/"`.

6. Now save the configuration.
7. Clear/Refresh magento cache.(It is very important)

I hope it will work

Comment: okay, we will try...

Comment: is it going to help in uploading the excel sheet fastly?

Comment: I am not sure about that because you purchased third party extension

Comment: you said to create sub- domain , is  sub - domain  site will be in different server or same server

Comment: Same server but sub domain

Comment: but client want in different server..

Comment: i think it will work different server Enter your server url in Base Media URL

Comment: okay, i will try....

Comment: I am facing different condition , when accessing image URL's its adding cache/ part in a URL , due to which I am unable to access images from media domain, can you help @Magento 2?

Comment: How is a subdomain running in the same server increasing performance?